# Handle multiple uploaded html file

Tags: javascript, html

My task is to upload multiple html files, and copy their content in my html.

And here is the html part:

`<input type="file" id="fi" onChange="xx();" multiple>UPLOAD</span>`

JavaScript part:

```
function xx (){        

    var fi = document.getElementById('fi').files[0];

    reader.onload = function (e){

        var reader = new FileReader();


        var inn = document.getElementById("main_text");  
        inn.innerHTML="";        
        var inner ="";
        inner  += this.result;                         
        inn.innerHTML ="<div class='paper'>"+inner+"</div>";
        <!--codes-->

    }
    reader.readAsText(fi);
}
```

I've already deleted useless parts in my code. Originally it can only handle single file. Then I added `multiple` attribute in html input code.

It seems that in this line, the last `files[0]`decides which file to read. 
`var fi = document.getElementById('fi').files[0];`

How can I modify it to archive the goal of handling multiple html pages in uploading functions?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over the files :

```
function xx (){        

    var fi     = document.getElementById('fi').files;
    var inn    = document.getElementById("main_text");
    var div    = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'paper';
    inn.appendChild(div);

    for (var i=0; i<fi.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e){
            var txt = document.createTextNode(this.result);
            div.appendChild(txt);
        }
        reader.readAsText(fi[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks a lot! When I applied your code I found that if I add `console.log(html)` in the iteration after `html+=...`, the result is right. But when I put it outside the iteration before`inn.innerhtml`, no log was presented. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: I correct my last comment:  when I put the test log outside after the iteration before`inn.innerhtml`, the LOG was shown before the LOG in iteration then displayed nothing

Comment: @Darklizard - yeah, I forgot that the fileReader is async, so the onload handler is executed after the innerHTML, need a solution for that as well, I'll change the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. If, as you mentioned, it is async, what can I do if I want to execute the codes which was originally placed in the `<--!codes-->`  in my question???

Comment: You'll have to figure out a way to execute that code inside the onload handler, it's hard to say exactly how without knowing what it is?

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you..and I found that `var txt = document.createTextNode(this.result);`
`div.appendChild(txt);` make my content covered with `double quote`. Is there any way to remove the `double quote` and make the browser see my imported content as html code?

Comment: You could try the `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + this.result;` trick ?